# What is the default element for Backbone view?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, backbone.js

When I use this

```
this.setElement($('#some-id'));
```

in backbone's view, what am I changing the element from? The parent DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `new Backbone.View()` shows that the default element (the wrapper for the view) is just a `<div>` that isn't attached to the DOM.

Not setting the `el` property of a view doesn't necessarily effect how your view is displayed. Ultimately, you will have to append your view to the DOM inside your render function. The `el` property is just a convenient way to keep track of where your view should go/is.